# Using NPM and node Supervisor

Tags: node.js

Just installed nodeJS and NPM and nodesupervisor via Terminal in OS 10.5.8.

I have a server running with:

```
var http = require("http");

function onRequest(request, response) {
  console.log("Request received.");
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World!");
  response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);

console.log("Server has started.");
```

How do I restart the server, without quitting Terminal if the following is updated:

```
response.write("Hello World, From NodeJS!");
```

I've seen this "^C" used in Terminal, in a NodeJS video TUT.

Also have node supervisor which appears to handle these changes, but when I attempt to use the watch "-w" command(supervisor -w server.js),
on server.js,  nothing ("file being watched" or something) is returned, and the supervisor help screen simply reloads.

NPM: 1.0.96
nodeJS: v0.4.11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ctrl-C is definitely the way to quit node without quitting terminal all together, just like most command-line apps.

A better option for you might be [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon). It is specifically for restarting node when changes to files are made.

To install:

`npm install nodemon -g`

Then simply execute your app with nodemon instead of node.

`nodemon server.js`

Comment: used  "node server.js" for starting the server, I'm confused why the Supervisor -w(watch) command was ignored in Terminal?

Answer (score 1):

How did you start the node server?

If you are using supervisor then you should be able to do the following:

```
supervisorctl stop all
```

Afterwards do whatever you did before to start the thing back up:

```
supervisord
```

Comment: What mistake did I make with Supervisor (-w) watch, or is my understanding of the app in err?