# Running node.js w/ supervisor in win8

Tags: node.js, windows-8, node-supervisor

I'm trying to get my node server running w/ supervisor. I had it working in Windows 7, but now it keeps failing. Here's the output:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\supervisor\lib\cli-wrapper.js --no-restart-on error server.js

DEBUG: Running node-supervisor with

CreateProcessW: The system cannot find the file specified.
DEBUG:   program 'server.js'
DEBUG:   --watch '.'
DEBUG:   --ignore 'undefined'
DEBUG:   --extensions 'node|js'
DEBUG:   --exec 'node'
DEBUG: Starting child process with 'node server.js'
DEBUG: Watching directory 'D:\Websites\MyProject' for changes.
DEBUG: Program node server.js exited with code 127
```

[This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7762775/65387) suggested trying nodemon instead, but the result is more or less the same:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\Mark\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nodemon\nodemon.js server.js
26 Jan 22:23:10 - [nodemon] v0.7.1
26 Jan 22:23:10 - [nodemon] watching: D:\Websites\MyProject
26 Jan 22:23:10 - CreateProcessW: The system cannot find the file specified.
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
26 Jan 22:23:10 - [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

However, if I run "vanilla" node.js, it starts up fine:

```
"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" server.js
Listening on http://localhost:8081
```

What might be the problem? Is it the `server.js` file it can't find? Why wouldn't it be able to find it?

Comment: Thought maybe it wanted `git`... does not appear to be the case.

Comment: This looks related: https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/3968 Not sure what "which" is though

Answer (score 1):

Rebooted Windows, problem went away. It starts up fine now. Probably just needed to restart either Windows or my IDE to refresh some file paths :-)